# Zoom problem while using onWheel with react-avatar-editor

Tags: reactjs

I'am working on a React app and i use react-avatar-editor to resize a user profil picture, i have a problem while trying to zoom in the picture, at one point the zoom also applies to the browser tab instead of just the picture,

```
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import AvatarEditor from "react-avatar-editor";

const Avatar = () => {
  const editorRef = useRef(null);
  const [profilePhoto, setProfilePhoto] = useState(() => {
    return localStorage.getItem("profilePhoto");
  });
  const [scale, setScale] = useState(1);

  const handleFileChange = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files?.[0];
    if (file) {
      setProfilePhoto(file);
    }
  };

  const handleZoomChange = (e) => {
    const newScale = scale + e.deltaY * -0.01;
    setScale(Math.min(Math.max(1, newScale), 2));
    //e.stopPropagation();
  };

  return (
    <div onWheel={handleZoomChange}>
      <input type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={handleFileChange} />
      <AvatarEditor
        ref={editorRef}
        image={profilePhoto}
        width={250}
        height={250}
        borderRadius={50}
        scale={scale}
      />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          if (editorRef.current) {
            const editedImage = editorRef.current
              .getImageScaledToCanvas()
              .toDataURL();
            localStorage.setItem("profilePhoto", editedImage);
            setProfilePhoto(editedImage);
          }
        }}
      >
        Save
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Avatar;
```

i try the stopPropagation() function but it didn't work